# Displaying menu after click on Button: why is my code not working?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, contextmenu

I have a **fragment** with a single `Button`. My goal is to display `menu_language.xml` whenever the user clicks on that button. I tried to find an answer online and that's the closest I could get to it... but it's not working: if I press the button **nothing happens**. What's wrong in this code?

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fgm = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        Button changeLanguageBtn = (Button) fgm.findViewById(R.id.change_language_button);
        changeLanguageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().openOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
        return fgm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
        if (view.getId() == R.id.change_language_button) { // is this even necessary?
            MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_language, menu);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_english:
                // switch to English 
                return true;
            case R.id.action_italian:
                // switch to Italian 
                return true;
            case R.id.action_french:
                // switch to French 
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Here's the xml of the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_italian"
            android:title="@string/italian" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_english"
            android:title="@string/english" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_french"
            android:title="@string/french" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: are you using a Toolbar ?

Comment: There is a Toolbar, but `change_language_button` is **not there**: it's in the middle of the screen.

Comment: I think you implemented the wrong method, onCreateOptionsMenu vs onCreateContextMenu

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Options menu, you implemented context menu.

[see instructions here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong method (if you want to add a menu to the `ActionBar`:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
```

If you read that method's Javadoc:

```
/**
     * Called when a context menu for the {@code view} is about to be shown.
     * Unlike {@link #onCreateOptionsMenu}, this will be called every
     * time the context menu is about to be shown and should be populated for
     * the view (or item inside the view for {@link AdapterView} subclasses,
     * this can be found in the {@code menuInfo})).
     * <p>
     * Use {@link #onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)} to know when an
     * item has been selected.
     * <p>
     * The default implementation calls up to
     * {@link Activity#onCreateContextMenu Activity.onCreateContextMenu}, though
     * you can not call this implementation if you don't want that behavior.
     * <p>
     * It is not safe to hold onto the context menu after this method returns.
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
```

Whereas:

`public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {`

says:

```
/**
     * Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu.  You
     * should place your menu items in to <var>menu</var>.  For this method
     * to be called, you must have first called {@link #setHasOptionsMenu}.  See
     * {@link Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu}
     * for more information.
     *
     * @param menu The options menu in which you place your items.
     *
     * @see #setHasOptionsMenu
     * @see #onPrepareOptionsMenu
     * @see #onOptionsItemSelected
     */
```

So If you want to add a menu to the activity, you have to use the later. Now if you wanted to show a *contextual* menu anchored to the button you pressed, then look at [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) class.

Regarding your `is this needed?` comment, the answer is *most likely no* in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to use **Options Menu** as you suggested but I can't make it work. Would you mind fixing directly the code I should use in this case?

Comment: I'm a little bit busy atm, I haven't used menus in a while but from what I recall, you will want to implement `public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {` when the button is press you can set a flag/boolean to indicate whether you want to show (or hide) the menu. onPrepareOptionsMenu will make the decision (since it's receiving a menu) to add/remove items to that menu (which you can inflate from XML if you want). Give that a try and let us know how it went. Search for: "Modify menu programmatically at runtime android" or similar and you will likely find a lot of samples. Good luck!

Comment: Also I _think_ you need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` so the callback gets called (but I can't remember atm)